# Showing some subset of a topological space is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

It may be trivial but I am going to show that a set $S$ that has the following property is disconnected:

Consider a topological space $(X, \tau)$. $S$ is a subset of $X$ and $A$, $B$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$.
$$
S \subseteq A \cup B\\
S \cap A \neq \varnothing \land S \cap B \neq \varnothing
$$
Then, $S$ is a disconnected set.

My proof: $S = S \cap (A\cup B) = (S\cap A) \cup (S\cap B)$. $S$ is open in the subspace $S$ of $X$. Hence, $S \cap A$ and $S \cap B$ are open in $S$ and because $A$, $B$ are disjoint, so are they. $S$ is the union of two disjoint open subsets of $S$. Therefore, $S$ is disconnected.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine. Another way to prove it (less elegant though) is to assume by contradiction it is connected, then since it is in $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then it must be in only one of them, contradicting the fact that $S \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $S \cap B \neq \emptyset$.